# Undefined chars wrote by low-level function write() on a file

Tags: c, file, structure, low-level

Currently, as exercise, I am building a small database using C programming Language. The database will be structured as a collection of structures. Each structure contain specific elements (in this case id, username and password). In the following code I am testing writing an item inside the database(which is no more than a file). The only problems I am experiencing are the actual chars written on the file and the fact that when I try to read the contend of the file nothing is printed on the terminal screen.

```
Here is the full code:
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct obj{
    unsigned id;
    char *username;
    char *password;
};

struct obj new_dat_elem;

int main(){
    int fd;
    int n;
    char buf[4096];

    new_dat_elem.id = 0;
    new_dat_elem.username = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) + strlen("Name") + 1);
    strcpy(new_dat_elem.username, "Name");
    new_dat_elem.password = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) + strlen("Password") + 1);
    strcpy(new_dat_elem.username, "Password");

    if((fd = open("database.txt", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, 0)) != -1){
        if((n = write(fd, &new_dat_elem, sizeof(new_dat_elem))) != -1){
            printf("SUCCESS: %d bytes written of the file\n", n);
            close(fd);
        }
    }
    if((fd = open("database.txt", O_RDONLY, 0)) != -1){
        if((n = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) != -1){
            write(0, buf, n);
        }
    }
}
```

Content of database.txt after 1 program run:

```
    
· 
·
```

Can someone please explain me what this chars are and why they are written on the file? Even hex dumping the database-file, the values makes no sense. Furthermore, I suppose that maybe the fact that nothing is shown on screen in the last part of the code depend on this problem... Thanks in advance.

Comment: `write(0, buf, n);` is unusual; 0 is the file number for `stdin`.  That does happen to work in some cases, though, like when run on a terminal it's normal for descriptors 0, 1, and 2 to all refer to a single share file description opened read+write on the TTY.  But it means `foo > out.txt` will still output to the terminal, and `foo < bar.txt` will fail to output anything.  Use `strace ./a.out` to trace the system calls you're making, and look at the file contents with `hexdump -C database.txt` or `less database.txt` to check for non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Your `write()` call writes one `struct obj`.  That contains `unsigned id`, an unsigned integer, `char *username`, a pointer to character, and `char *password`, another pointer to character.  Assuming your `write()` call actually worked (and you're not really checking that - read the man age for `write()`), those three elements and any padding are exactly what was written.  Think about that for a bit.

Comment: Note that the `struct obj` contains a couple of pointers.  Those prevent you from serializing the structure easily.  In particular, `write(fd, &new_dat_elem, sizeof(new_dat_elem))` only writes the bytes representing the pointers, not the data that the pointers point at.  You can't read that information back in usefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you expecting to be in the file when you write this out

```
   struct obj{
       unsigned id;
       char *username;
       char *password;
    };
```

do you expect

```
 42, dave, magic
```

That wont happen, instead you will get a string of bytes (size depends on your computer)

```
             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 value of id ........
 value of name ptr   ................
 value of password ptr               ................
```

You can see that if you do a hex dump of the file using `od` on linux or something like hxd on windows.

If you want the text you have to do something completely different.

BTW you might not be getting the output I say since you are never testing that any of the IO operations work, but once you make them work correctly then this is what you will get

In particular note that those strings are not written out

Comment: What do you mean with “testing” the IO operations? Isn’t it enough  checking if the actual function returns -1, as explained in K&R book? Furthermore, now that you have explained it to me, since on the file are written the actual bytes of the content inside the structure , non concerning about the format, is it still possible to read them and check for example if a certain username or password was inserted?

Comment: @FrancescoMobilia First question: yes, I mean testing the result to make sure it worked.

Comment: @FrancescoMobilia SEcond question: The code you have does not write the username and password to the file. You need to do `fprintf` not `write`

Comment: I have worked a bit more on the project and I solve all my problems.  I am still using `write()`, this time though I am taking separately each element of the structure and printing them in a specific format on the file. Thanks for the support btw.